# opening file from CSV and returning it with strip and split function

Tags: python

so this is my code for the question, there is a CSV file containing 2 rows of info, however when you just split the data you will end up getting /n at the end of all rows, hence why there is a strip in the function. But i don't know how to use the function properly, hope some pro can help fix this function up thanks. Also i need to somehow turn it into a tuple which i have no idea what to do.

```
def load_friends(filename):
    v = []
    with open(filename, 'Ur') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.split(',')
            line.append(tuple)
    return v
    f.close
```

Comment: You aren't calling `f.close` btw, it's after the return statemetn, also you should write, `f.close()`, however you don't need to since `with` calls the `close` method of the file for you,

Comment: You failed to notice that you constantly override your "line" variable - and add nothing to "v"!

Comment: yup was returning blank info it all works now tho ! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def load_friends(filename):
    v = []
    with open(filename, 'Ur') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip()
            line = line.split(',')
            line = tuple(line)
            v.append(line)
    return v
```

You need to convert to a tuple and append it with `+`. `line.append(tuple)` has no meaning, it just appends a dataype to the list `line`.

Alternatively,

```
def load_friends(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        return [tuple(line.strip().split(',')) for line in f]
```

Comment: No need for the list comp, it just wastes an intermediate list

Comment: @jamylak: I don't quite get you.. Are you talking about the alternative method?

Comment: I'm just saying you can lose the `[`, `]`. It will become a generator expression to the tuple constructor which will be much more efficient (yes on the alternative)

Comment: jamylak's answer came out correctly with the [(data)], where as yours be comes (( data )). From what i remembered it meant to be the square bracket, from your first method how would you go by getting that ?

Comment: @Manishearth I didn't downvote btw, im guessing it's to do with your first code since your second one is fine

Comment: @NUBatcodes: Oh, I thought you wanted everything to be a tuple. One second, I'll edit that.

Comment: @jamylak: Probably due to the OPs comment above. Fixed now :)

Comment: ah haha sorry i am really new at this, it hard for me to explain everything in the right format/ language.

Comment: haha can only pick one right answer but yes you are both right, just jamylak seems short and advance hard for me to understand atm but same outcome :D. thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel, use the [standard `csv` library](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html):

```
import csv

def load_friends(filename):
    with open(filename, 'Ur') as f:
        v = [tuple(rec) for rec in csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')]
    return v
```

Comment: oops forgot about `csv` + 1

Comment: same outcome thanks, don't really understand how the delimiter works tho

Comment: @NUBatcodes - `csv.reader` needs `delimiter` to know, where to `split` the line. However, it does a great job with lines like `"First, field", "second, field"` returning two elements only (`line.split` would return four).

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want. This is a simplification of your code, however use the solution by @eumiro since the `csv` library was built for this.

```
def load_friends(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rU') as f:
        return [tuple(line.strip().split(',')) for line in f]
```